# Expanding the HTML view

Tags: theming

I am new to Drupal and am having trouble getting my custom HTML to take up most of the page. As you can see below, it is confined to the center and takes up a tiny percentage of the screen.

Here is the image of my module:

[image: My custom HTML]

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should't use a Drupal default theme. As when you update Drupal core, you're going to overwrite all your theme files. So if you want to use a default Drupal theme you need to create a sub theme, if you haven't already. Follow this tutorial [Creating A Drupal 7 Sub Theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xB7qjZlVKQo).

Secondly, it looks small because you have items in your left column.

Thus, you need to remove the left column blocks. Go to /admin/structure/block and disable those blocks. **OR** Edit those blocks and in the **Show block on specific pages** you can control on which pages you want them to show up or be excluded from.

If that still doesn't do it, you need to edit your theme files. Go to /sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/ **folder** and edit the page.tpl.php file and get rid off the left column.

Even after doing this, if you still want it bigger, then right mouse click on the page and select inspect element. Find the name of the div class or id that is controlling your output.

example `<div id="hello" class="cool">`

then on your css you put

`#hello { width: 5000px; }` if its and ID

`.cool { width: 5000px; }` if its class

If it has both, pick whichever you want

BTW: Your themes css file is located in the sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/css folder.

**Finally, after you make changes always remember to clear/empty your cache**

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few contributed (+ free of charge) themes you may want to look at (assuming your using Drupal version 7):

- [Zen](https://www.drupal.org/project/zen).
- [Omega](https://www.drupal.org/project/omega).
- [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap).
- [Zeropoint](https://www.drupal.org/project/zeropoint).

Actually there are [hundreds of great themes](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_theme?f%5B0%5D=&f%5B1%5D=&f%5B2%5D=drupal_core%3A103&f%5B3%5D=sm_field_project_type%3Afull&text=&solrsort=iss_project_release_usage%20desc&op=Search).

When cherry picking from this list, you may want to use criteria such as responsive, fluid (that appears to be one of the issues you're struggling with), base theme, etc ...